# Have separated networks in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have a question how to separate networks in docker?

We have to locally start 2 times the same application, but the problem is if I try to start them in the same time I got an error because they start on the same port, so I was thinking if it's possible to separate the networks so they can start at the same time, without I have to manually change the ports?

The ultimate goal would be to run the same app but from different branches and run the Cypress tests (also from Docker) for each branch at the same time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your applications in different services, you don't need to create separate networks, because docker starts them in different containers with different networks. You only need to change the port, which you can access the container, but the applications ports stay the same.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app1:
    build: ./app
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
  app2:
    build: ./app
    ports:
    - 8081:8080
```

In this example the 'app1' runs on port 8080 in the container, and the mapped port is also 8080. The 'app2' runs on port 8080, but the mapped port is 8081, so you access it on 8081.

Answer (score 0):

@Máté Tősér
Thank you for the reply.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres_changes:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=user
    ports:
      - '${db_port:-5433}:5432'
    mem_limit: 50m
    networks:
      - network

  api_changes:
    image: node:14.16.0
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - postgres_changes
    ports:
      - '${api_port:-8080}:8080'
    working_dir: /opt
    environment:
      - WEB_URL=http://localhost:${web_port:-3000}
      - API_URL=http://localhost:${api_port:-8080}
      - PORT=${port:-8080}
      - DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
    volumes:
      - clone:/opt
      - ./packages/api/.env:/.env
      - ./packages/api/config.json:/packages/api/config.json
    command: sh -c "git checkout ${branch:-development}
      && cd ./packages/api
      && npx sequelize db:drop
      && npx sequelize db:create
      && yarn migrate
      && yarn seed
      && yarn ci:populate
      && yarn start:dev"
    mem_limit: 500m
    networks:
      - network

  web_changes:
    image: node:14.16.0
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - api_changes
    ports:
      - '${web_port:-3000}:3000'
    working_dir: /opt
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080
    volumes:
      - clone:/opt
      - ./packages/web/.env:.env
      - ./packages/web/src/config.json:/packages/web/src/config.json
    stdin_open: true
    command: sh -c "cd ./packages/web && yarn start"
    mem_limit: 1g
    networks:
      - network

volumes:
  clone:
    name: ${volume_name:-clone}

networks:
  network:
    name: $network_name
    # internal: true
```

This is what I was thinking and make run it on other ports but is this the right way? Or it is better to run them (if it's possible) on a different network?
Because I've tried to rename to another network - but it's like they are again on the same network, and also tried use the "internal: true" but than it won't work.